# Consumer Proxy unable to pick up messages from queue due to service configuration in flux

Tags: weblogic, soa, osb

The Consumer proxy is not picking up messages from queue. We have redeployed service and restarted servers. But it did not help. I am attaching logs in here.

<01-Mar-2019 10:39:53 o'clock GMT>     
<01-Mar-2019 10:39:53 o'clock GMT>

Comment: I am attaching Logs in here. Please help. <01-Mar-2019 10:39:53 o'clock GMT> <Error> <WliSbTransports> <BEA-381519> <Failure while processing an incoming message for endpoint ProxyService LogCustomerEvent_Business_v1/proxy/JMS_LogCustomerEvent due to service configuration in flux> 
<01-Mar-2019 10:39:53 o'clock GMT> <Error> <WliSbTransports> <BEA-381502> <Exception in JmsInboundMDB.onMessage: com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportException: Failure while processing an incoming message for endpoint ProxyService CustomerEvent_Business_v1/proxy/JMS_CustomerEvent due to service configuration in flux

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle support document [1573359.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=200678033641232&id=1573359.1&displayIndex=1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=o6h4kww0s_97):

CAUSE
 The service has been re-deployed/changed while there were messaging being processed. Review Doc ID 1571958.1 "OSB SBConsole Activation - Limitations for configuration or deployment changes in production" for other reasons that this error can occur.

SOLUTION
Stop consumption on the jms queue, delete and re-deploy service.

1. Log in to Weblogic Console
2. Expand services -> Messaging -> JMS Modules -> Select the Queue your service is interacting with.
3. Select the Control tab
4. For both production and consumption, select pause.
5. Wait a short while (5 minutes) and restart the queue
6. Re-deploy your Proxy Services

If message still persist please check config.xml and make sure that there is a correct number of applications with name starting with  "*ALSB*". The correct number depends on the kind of services you have deployed. JMS request-response, JMS plain request, JMS topic etc...

The easiest way to make sure that config.xml is correct is to do the following:

1. Delete all the JMS proxies from OSB configuration
2. Open WLS console go to "Deployments" and make sure that there are no application "_ALSB_xyz" deployed. If they are present delete them.
3. Re-deploy JMS proxies

Alternately, check Note 1382976.1 to locate the related deployments. Delete any application deployments starting with "*ALSB*" which are not related to any actively deployed JMS proxy service.

Comment: Thanks Wesley. This has worked for me. I followed the step-by -step guide. And there is no flux error in server due to which consumer proxy is unable to pick messages up from queue.